# error: function declared 'noreturn' should not return

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, lambda

At my workplace, we have a different internal name for `noreturn` attribute. Suppose it is `INTERNAL_DONT_RETURN`

I am writing a member function of a class where I do something like

```
INTERNAL_DONT_RETURN void foo() const
{
    if(!*this)
    {
       throw CoolException();
    }
    m_call_throw();
}
```

This m_call_throw() is a private class member `std::function<void()>m_call_throw`  which gets populated in the class's constructor as a lambda. This lambda does nothing but

`m_call_throw([uncoolID]() { throw UncoolException(uncoolID); })`

Now both, gcc-4.9.3 and clang gives me following warning

`error: function declared 'noreturn' should not return [-Werror,-Winvalid-noreturn]
        }
        ^`

I have already consulted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452489/warning-noreturn-function-does-return) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964219/noreturn-function-does-return) question but none of them explained the cause of above warning.

1) Is compiler implicitly adding `return` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23452545/1410711) ?

2) Even when I am throwing exceptions why does compiler believe that my function will return?

3) [noreturn attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2//gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bnoreturn_007d-function-attribute-2160) mentions that

> The noreturn keyword does not affect the exceptional path when that
>   applies: a noreturn-marked function may still return to the caller by
>   throwing an exception or calling longjmp.

Is this relevant to my problem?

Comment: please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

But you do return! You return by falling of the end of the function, if the if-statement is false. You may know this can never happen because `m_call_throw()` never returns either (does it?), but the compiler apparently doesn't understand this logic.

Is `m_call_throw()` marked as noreturn? If not, add it. And if the compiler doesn't pick up on that, you could add an additional throw at the end of the function which you know is never reached but which should silence the warning.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler cannot prove the function will always throw. This is not a bug — there always will be cases that a compiler cannot prove either way.

Whether it should warn you or not is an interesting question. Warning you means it will sometimes report a bug that is not there; not warning you means it will sometimes miss a real bug.

You can easily make the warning non-fatal, or silence it in a number of ways. Disable it for this particular file, or add a call to `abort` at the end. There are tradeoffs to be made in each case, but that's life.

If you can switch from a lambda/std::function to a normal member function, just do so, and make it `noreturn`. Alas, you cannot have a `noreturn` function type or a `noreturn` `std::function` or a `noreturn` lambda, which is IMHO a bug in the language.

Comment: +1 for adding that we cant have (yet) a noreturn function type or a noreturn std::function or a noreturn lambda

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `foo` returns, or at least, *seems to return*.

When a function declared with `noreturn`, then that function must not return:

```
void Foo() __attribute__((noreturn));

void Foo()
{
    // The application will exit, without returning.
    exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    Foo();
}
```

You know that your `m_call_throw` will not return either, but the compiler doesn't.

So explicitly telling the compiler it does not might help as follows:

```
void Foo() __attribute__((noreturn));
void m_call_throw() __attribute__((noreturn));

void Foo()
{
    // Ok, no return huh?
    m_call_throw();
}
```

Live demo is [here](http://ideone.com/VSfFdJ).